# Displaying Firebase array results In polymer dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-realtime-database

When receiving an array of data from firebase web SDK

You must first load the data.

```
firebase.database().ref(path).once('value', function(snapshot) {
   // assume the data is an array of objects like
   // h7weoahfno4bfnuyb4 : {
   //     data1: 'some data',
   //     data2: 'some data',
   //     data3: 'some more data'
   // },
   // sadfasdfgq4qgq43gf : {
   //     ...
   // }
   // and so on

  // now, add it to an array
  this.set('data', snapshot.val());
});
```

Where the random string is the one given by firebase.

Using `dom-repeat` the  won't work being that the value returned is a JavaScript Object.

I therefore convert it to an array, using a function like

```
_toArray: function(obj) {
                return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
                    return {
                        name: key,
                        value: obj[key]
                    };
                });
            },
```

and setting the data like :

```
var value = that._toArray(snapshot.val());
this.set('data', value);
```

My problem comes from when data changes, how can I apply it to the array.
If for example one child changes I get a snapshot of its data and key, whitch could be used to this.set('data.'+key, newData);

But because its an array I can't do that.

I guess I could loop though checking `if(this.data[i].name === newDataUID)`
but that seems very messy.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is messy code only then you can use `findIndex` method of [lodash](https://libraries.io/bower/lodash) which internally uses `while` loop to iterate over the array.